# animation.enabled = false on start call but when i run the game, animation has starting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make walking animation for my character when he walk but animation always running.sorry for my english. here is my code;

```
  
   Animator anim;
 
   void Start ()
{      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
   anim.enabled = false;
}

   void walk(){
      if(body.velocity > 0){
         anim.enabled = true;
         anim.Play("walk");
      }
      if(Vector2.zero){
         anim.enabled = false;
      }
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
{  
   body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `if (Vector2.zero)` makes no sense.

Maybe try using the `else` keyword and add a `anim.Stop` to the second part:

```
  if(body.velocity > 0){
     anim.enabled = true;
     anim.Play("walk");
  }
  else {
     anim.Stop()
     anim.enabled = false;
  }
```